# Display a different default value after selected an option

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

What I want to achieve is after a user selects an option, the input would then display "select another option" instead of display the value name of the selected option.

Basic example:

```html
<select>
<option value="" selected>Select an Option</option>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Attach a `change` event listener to the `select` that checks whether this is the first time the user selected an option. If it is, you can set the value to `""` and set the `textContent` of the selected option to "Select another option."

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select');
var isFirst = true;
select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (isFirst) {
    select.value = "";
    select.options[select.selectedIndex].textContent = "select another option";
    isFirst = false
  }
})
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="" selected>Select an Option</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

If you want to do it everytime the user selects an option:

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select');
select.addEventListener('change', function() {
  select.value = "";
  select.options[select.selectedIndex].textContent = "select another option";
})
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="" selected>Select an Option</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```